# facebook login oauth and osx 10.11/CNA

Tags: facebook, macos, facebook-graph-api, oauth

a little background:
I have an hotspot page wich integrate with facebook login oatuh. The app runs on facebook api v.2.4 and uses node/express/passport to handle the login process
The only option i pass to the oauth fb page is display: touch, so the login page works fine without cookie support

the issue:
since a few days , only on osx 10.11/cna the login can't be processed because of no cookie support in CNA (this should mean that fb ignores the display option, in this case only)

the same request made from a ios device from within the cna works fine

I've already confirmed the display option is actually send, so my best guess is that fb started overwriting/ignoring this option. Also I can't find any reference in the fb api docs anymore (except for display=popup in the manual login page)

Any hint about this ?

thanks

g

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: I have the same problem. I have partially solved it by bypassing completely the CNA. To do so, I have added apple.com (and all subdomains) to the Walled Garden whitelist. On Chilli + OpenWRT, you need to login in your router and add apple.com to HS_UAMDOMAINS in /etc/chilli/defaults. In this way, the CNA browser won't open because the probe URL (http://captive.apple.com/hotspot-detect.html, defined in /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/CaptiveNetworkSupport/Settings.plist) is now reachable. I know this is a bit hackish, but it worked for me :-)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you still have this issue, but I can confirm facebook login definitely works end to end inside the CNA on 10.11. The CNA does allow cookies, what it doesn't allow is access to existing cookies in safari or access to localStorage and sessionStorage.

If you have your FB sdk configured with cookies=false, this may well be your issue. When set to false I believe the sdk is then attempting to use local storage.

The other thing to check would be what you have in the walled garden list. We have just got to the bottom of this issue after a lot of frustration. Allowing certain CDN networks actually causes iOS to complete it's internet check and no longer think it's behind a captive portal. I added an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/41273984/4427589.

As I said, I can confirm it definitely works end to end inside the popup.

Cheers
Paul