# Facebook login on Apple CNA

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, captiveportal

Questions:

- Is it possible to set up Facebook login for use in the CNA?
- Does CNA documentation exist for developers?
- Can you debug the CNA screen using any developer tools?

Details:

I have created a captive portal login page that uses an email submission form or a Facebook login button.  The login button uses javascript as documented on Facebook's developer resources to open a window and log the user in.

Testing:

- CNA:  Clicking the Facebook sign in button redirects to the facebook login, after multiple clicks.  Facebook login page allows submission of username and password but does not generate these entries from cookies.  After submission, the page is blank and login is not completed.
- Full Featured Browsers:  In Safari, Chrome, Firefox, etc. the social sign is functioning and works as expected.  All browsers redirect the user to the login page, the user may use the email submission button or the social sign to authenticate on the hotspot and redirected to a landing page.  The problems only occur on the CNA.

Research:

Forums threads state that it's impossible to use Facebook login in this way but I'm not sold because [Social Sign In](http://www.socialsign.in/) seems to be doing exactly what I'm proposing. They claim to accomplish the login without using apps so I have to assume their using either a CNA browser or launching Safari directly.  Some javascript is functional in the CNA but I'm unable to track down resources to explain exactly what the capabilities/limitations of the CNA are.

Thanks for any help on this issue

Comment: Did you find a solution in the end? :)

Comment: No luck yet, Denis. I will be sure to follow up if I find a solution. Thanks for your interest!

Comment: Hi! I have the same problem, I partially solved it by bypassing the CNA altogether, by adding apple.com to the Walled Garden whitelist. I know it's hackish, but it worked for me :-) See my comment on http://stackoverflow.com/q/36128510/2972183 for more details.

Comment: @GuidoWalterPettinari I'm assuming that the user does not get a prompt now and would need to use a browser to see the login.  I will do some testing and see if that solves my problem.  Thanks for tipping me off to the thread!

Comment: @bdub, exactly. The biggest issue with this approach is that the hotspot user won't be able to login unless s/he opens the browser and visits a non-https website. Therefore, you need to instruct the users to do so. For example, if they open the Facebook App or Google.com, they won't be able to login, but if they visit http://StackOverflow.com they will.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: No, unfortunately, and I'm working on new projects now.  Best of luck!