# Javascript Facebook sdk - captive portal on mobile devices

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, captiveportal, coovachilli

We are setting up a web app which serves as a wi-fi hotspot using coova chilli and the Javascript Facebook SDK.

The app has a "login with facebook" button that, once clicked, calls the FB.login() function, which opens a pop-up window where the user can insert his credentials and log in.

This solution is working correctly in desktop browsers but it's not working in mobile devices.

These are the problems I encountered:

1. Android device - When I connect to the wifi network, the system prompts a notification who says "Sign in to wifi network". Once clicked, the captive page opens up correctly. But when I click the fb login button, I am redirected to the url "http://m.facebook.com/v2.8/auth ..." which is correct, but then the windows freezes and I can see only a wsod.
2. IOS device - same as before, the cna triggers, the redirect to the fb login page works, but once I insert my credentials, the only thing I can see is a wsod.

Both issues can be bypassed by including apple.com, google.com and other domains used for auth in the hotspot walled garden, and then the user can log in to the network by using the device's browser - Safari or Chrome, it works - as pointed out in this discussion [Facebook login on Apple CNA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39495989/facebook-login-on-apple-cna).

The thing is, we want to make it work on the "normal" workflow, that is, to make the app work correctly within the IOS captive network assistant and the Android "sign in to wi fi" functionality.

Do you have any idea how can we solve this? We searched far and wide without any success. Thank you.

**EDIT**

Solved by using PHP SDK instead of javascript. By generating a login link as explained [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login). This works also on mobile captive portal assistants such as ios and android ones because the fb login page is opened in the same window and not in popup/iframe. I hope this helps others that may encounter the same problem.

Comment: I am trying to do something similar. I am not able to get sign in to wifi network dialog, can you direct me to the iptables or dnsmasq configurations that will help me achieve this. Thank you so much.

Comment: It seems that the problem is due to restrictions on the iOS and Android captive portal assistant, which apparentely don't allow pop-up dialogs to be shown. I think you better use server-side auth with PHP or Java instead, which redirects the user to a separate page instead of using a pop-up.

Comment: Hi @JesperSG I am facing a problem which i think you shall be solved on your project. Could you see this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44577224/dns-on-raspberry-coovachilli-captive-portal/44593352#44593352