# dns on raspberry coovachilli captive portal

Tags: dns, raspberry-pi3, captiveportal, bind9, coovachilli

I have a captive portal working on a raspberry. My coovachilli is working with an IP and when i connect, i am redirected to login page (http://10.10.10.1:4990...) As i told, it is working fine. But now, i need to put facebook login on this page. To do a facebook login i first need to configure my application on facebook and there i can't set an IP as site URL(facebook don't allow), i must to put a DNS. Then i tried, without success, to configure a internal DNS.

I tried those tutorials here:
https://www.howtoforge.com/two_in_one_dns_bind9_views
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-a-private-network-dns-server-on-ubuntu-16-04

It still not working, if i connect on raspberry and try http://example.com:4990 i get page not found, but with ip it works as always.

I even tried to change /etc/hosts and add `10.10.10.1    example.com`, but it works only from inside of raspberry. I knew it, but was desesperated :(

I also put .example.com on coovachilli's allowed domains:
`HS_UAMDOMAINS="connect.facebook.net,.facebook.com,.example.com"`

**[UPDATE]**
I trespassed this issue by using firebase auth api instead of facebook api. Firebase allows IP, then i was able to put 10.10.10.1 as domain. Facebook login is working now, thanks to firebase, but it would be nice if the url were http://myUrl:4990 instead of http://10.10.10.1:4990

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **uamaliasname** option in coovachilli configuration.

Example:

```
# UAM Alias
HS_UAMALIASNAME="hotspot.domain.com"
```

Comment: Hi @pinkra I tried HS_UAMALIASNAME="example.com" and HS_UAMALIASNAME="www.example.com" but don't works.

Comment: Hi, where did you put that?

Comment: I put it on /etc/chilli/config

Comment: Is it written on /etc/chilli/main.conf ?

Comment: I didn't know about this file...  this configuration is not there. How could i do it? Other configurations I changed only in config file, are there as well.